# OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am using Pycharm and ran this in the terminal

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

It downloaded successfully, and when i ran my code

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

this error comes up

```
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

I don't know what to do. Do anyone have any idea what went wrong?

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: `import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")`

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by running CMD with admin!